# Represent MM-DD-YYYY as Day, Month Date

Tags: java

I want to represent date in the format MM-DD-YYYY as Day, Month Date

For example - represent `5-12-2015` as Tuesday, May 12. How can I do this?

Comment: Show what you have tried ?

Comment: Parse the `String` value using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), format the resulting date using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I am giving you the code to do this, you should first show us your efforts.

```
String date = "5-12-2015";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date d = format.parse(date);
DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd");
String finalDateString = format1.format(d);
System.out.println(finalDateString);
```

Comment: Guess you mean finalDateString = format1.format(d); Please edit it, and I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, its not working. This is the finalDateString Saturday, Dec 05, which is not 5-12-2015

Comment: You need the first format to be - DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

Comment: Seems you are using date format MM-dd-yyyy. Just change that in first DateFormat object. like @rickygrimes said

Comment: That's what I asked you to do. Please do that so I can accept your answer.